# One of the two line segments $OX$ and $OY$ is subset of another; analytic geometry proof

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, real-numbers

Let $\mathbb R^n$ with Euclidean distance be a Euclidean space.

Let $O=(0,0,...,0)$.

Let any line segment $AB$ from $A=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ to $b=(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)$ be defined as ${\{tA+(1-t)B:0\le t \le 1}\}$.

How to prove that for any two segments $OX$ and $OY$, where $Y=\lambda X$
 for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, either $OX \in OY$ or $OY \in OX$?

Comment: That's not true if you pick $Y=-X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone mentioned in a comment, we need the condition that $\lambda \geq 0$.  Also, I believe that the correct statement to prove should be that $OX \subseteq OY$ or $OY \subseteq OX$.

Given that $O = (0, 0, ..., 0)$, we can write $OX = \{ tX \; : \; 0\leq t \leq 1\}$, and similarly we can write $OY = \{ tY\; : \; 0\leq t \leq 1\}$.  Since $Y = \lambda X$ for some non-negative $\lambda$, then we have $\{OY = \{ t(\lambda X) \; : \; 0\leq t \leq 1\} = \{ (t\lambda) X \; : \; 0\leq t \leq 1\} = \{ tX \; : \; 0\leq t \leq \lambda\}$, where in the last equality we made the observation that \begin{equation}
\{t : 0\leq t \leq \lambda \} = \{t\lambda : 0 \leq t \leq 1\}.\end{equation}

So, we now see that $OY = \{ tX\; : \; 0\leq t \leq \lambda\}$ and $OX = \{ tX\; : \; 0\leq t \leq 1\}$.  From here we conclude that $OY \subset OX$ if $0 \leq \lambda < 1$, and $OX \subset OY $ if $\lambda > 1$, and that $OX = OY$ if $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: How to prove that ${\{t:0 \le t \le \lambda}\}={\{t \lambda: 0 \le t \le 1}\}$?

Comment: @asdasdfsss Think about the numbers in each of those sets.  As $t$ ranges from 0 to 1, where would $t\lambda$ range?

Comment: Intuitively, from $0$ to $\lambda$.

Comment: @asdasdfsss You're right.  Which is the same of numbers as $\{t : 0\leq  t \leq \lambda\}$, right?  Therefore the two sets are equal.